# Subject.toString() returns the list of principals but no the authenticated user name

Tags: java, jaas

```
 [java] Logged in as Subject:
 [java]     Principal: write
 [java]     Principal: read
 [java]     Principal: delete
```

That's the output of `javax.security.auth.Subject#toString()`. It's not returning the username, but it does return the principals properly.

What could be failing?

```
        logincontext.login();
        Subject subject = logincontext.getSubject();
        System.out.println("Logged in as " + subject.toString());
```

**edit**: it seems to be something normal. I have been checking lot of examples, and no one is returning the username. Don't know why whoever developed this added a Subject tag then...

Comment: Can we see your code? Post your toString() method and the Subject object please.

Comment: @Gladhus it's not developed my be. `import javax.security.auth.Subject;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems to be something normal. I have been checking lot of examples, and no one is returning the username. Don't know why whoever developed this added a Subject tag then...